# Substitute for std::array when using boost::asio read_some() function, boost::array crashes at read_some() function call

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, std

I am working on reading results from a socket read using boost's sockets and a char array. Based on examples I've seen online (including the Boost docs), I have this so far:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#define MAXSIZE 1000000
//...
void MyClass::processCommand(std::string command)
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint e(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 60151);  //Info for the connection I need to make...
  this->socket.open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
  this->socket.connect(e);
  this->socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(command, command.size());
  this->socket.send(boost::asio::buffer(command, command.size());

  std::array<char, MAXSIZE> buffer;
  this->socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer));
}
```

Based on examples I've seen, it seems this should work. I have a problem though; for whatever reason, my compiler (I'm working in Qt 5.2) seems to refuse to recognize std::array as valid. Even with the `#include <array>` line, the line defining buffer gives an error saying array isn't a member of std. My project lead and I worked for an hour or so trying a bunch of different ways to fix this, including entirely reinstalling the std libraries, but to no avail; the code will still recognize the `#include <array>` line as valid, but then not let me use std::array. I tried to work around this by instead defining buffer as `char buffer[MAXSIZE] = ""`, but while that compiles it crashes when it reaches the read_some command on the next line. I'm admittedly really new to using Boost, and I'm not sure if there's any other way I could define buffer to make it a valid parameter to pass to the read_some function. If anyone knows how to solve this (either how to pass buffer to read_some without crashes, or how to get std::array to work) I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

**NOTE**: The project I'm working on uses VS2008.

**UPDATE**: So far, in addition to the code in the sample code above, I have tried the following:

- declaring buffer as `char buffer[MAXSIZE];` This compiles, but the program freezes at the line calling `socket.read_some()`. I get the same result with `char buffer[MAXSIZE] = "";`
- declaring buffer as `boost::array<char, MAXSIZE> buffer;`, both with and without adding a directive line to include `boost/array.hpp`. This freezes at the same place.
- based on what I found [here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=516), tried declaring buffer as `std::tr1::array<char, MAXSIZE> buffer;`. Also along the same logic, I tried adding `using namespace std::tr1;` and then defining buffer as `array<char, MAXSIZE> buffer;`. Neither of these compiled; both gave errors on the line calling `read_some()` for argument type mismatches.

It did occur to me, it is possible, since the ones that seem like they should work tend to freeze at `read_some()`, that it's taking a long time to read and it's simply timing out? If that's the case I can work around that, I just don't know how to tell if that's what's going on or if it's just crashing.

Comment: You must use c++11 (something like -std=c++1) to `#include <array>`

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for the response, I tried using boost::array instead of std::array, but it still crashes at the same place :/

Comment: How can it crash? You claimed it didn't compile.

Comment: @juanchopanza sorry if that was vague, what I meant was the boost::array code crashes at the same point as the code with buffer[MAXSIZE] = "". It did compile unlike the std::array though

Comment: Please don't edit your question, once it has been answered, to make it into ( sort of ) a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It should be no problem: see it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4e6f06ef12d77e8)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#define MAXSIZE 1000000
//...
void processCommand(std::string command)
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket(io);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint e(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 60151);  //Info for the connection I need to make...

    socket.open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4());
    socket.connect(e);
    socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(command));
    socket.send(boost::asio::buffer(command));

    std::array<char, MAXSIZE> buf;
    socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf));
}

int main()
{
    processCommand("EHLO");
}
```

If you don't have C++11, use `boost::array` (with `boost/array.hpp`).

In all other cases, look at your compiler and potential reports of incompatibility in the Boost issue trackers

Comment: I just checked and our project uses VS2008, so it would seem I can't use C++11. However, when I added an include directive for boost/array.hpp and changed std::array to boost::array, it compiles but crashes at the line calling read_some(). Would you happen to have an idea what may cause that problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `std::array` `boost::array` `std::vector` and `std::string` as suggested here :

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried it using boost::array<char, MAXSIZE> instead of std::array<char, MAXSIZE> which seems to match overload 11 on that page, but although it compiles it crashes at the read_some line, do you happen to have an idea why that may be? Also I unfortunately couldn't get the std::array overloads to work, it is still telling me that array isn't a member of std :/

Comment: Well that's another question, go ahead and ask it in its own thread, with as much detail that could help figuring out what kind of crash happens.